# JSF application crossing user session data

Tags: spring, jsf, richfaces, session-scope

I have a difficult JSF issue  I am trying to solve.  Note, I am fairly new to JSF and Java....I have a simple application where users login, select some checkboxes, click submit, add some more info on another page, save to DB and logout.

In my Production env, I am seeing instances where user session data is getting crossed or cached and pickup by a subsequent user session.  For example, User A enters data, then User B enters data and upon reviewing his data, he sees stuff User A entered.  Of course, I cannot recreate this in test.

I am using jsf 1.2._12, richfaces 3.3.2, and spring 2.5.6.  The app server is JBoss 5.

All of my JSF managed-beans are session scoped. This particular managed bean calls a spring bean as my Business object which is session scoped, which ultimately calls a DAO that is singleton.

Here the relavant faces-config info

```
<managed-bean>
    <description>ContactBean</description>
    <managed-bean-name>ContactBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.package.ContactBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>dataElementBO</property-name>
        <value>#{dataElementBO}</value>
    </managed-property>

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>attributeBO</property-name>
        <value>#{attributeBO}</value>
    </managed-property>

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>dataElement2BO</property-name>
        <value>#{dataElement2BO}</value>
    </managed-property>

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>submissionBO</property-name>
        <value>#{submissionBO}</value>
    </managed-property>

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>selectedList</property-name>
        <property-class>java.util.ArrayList</property-class>
        <list-entries />
    </managed-property>

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>enteredContact</property-name>
        <property-class>java.util.ArrayList</property-class>
        <list-entries />
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

And my app-Context for the spring bean getting called

```
<bean id="submissionBO" class="com.package.submissionBOImpl" scope="session">
    <property name="submissionDAO">
        <ref bean="submissionDAO" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

In viewing my webserver logs, this issue occurred when User A and B weren't even logged in at the same time.  User A logged out and then User B logged in almost 20 minutes later.

I don't understand how the use of session scoped beans could possibly cross in other users data... is there something I don't understand about how these are scoped?  I can attach some mocked up code if needed.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't assigning session scoped data as a `static` field in some class, are you? As to the local testing, just spawn different browsers on the same site at the same time, like Firefox, Chrome, Safari and/or IE.

Comment: The only statics I am using in the managed bean or spring bean are for my log and a  reg ex pattern used to check a phone number format in a validator method.

Comment: Sounds spooky and scary. Why did you use spring instead of seam? Seam is 100 folds better for jsf apps.

Comment: As a newbie, I was told the same thing by the developer that was teaching me... however, the "powers that be" said "no Seam for me", presumably because they didn't want to introduce another technology in the environment... so that is what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are submit and review pages using same managed-bean? If not how you passed data to other page?

Comment: I figured it out.. besc, your comment is along the right track.  The review page was using the same managed bean but was ultimately using a singleton spring bean to fetch data that the user reviews and  selects from (think data table with boolean checkboxes on each row). The flow is to fetch the data (bound to a singleton spring BO), selects some rows from that data (both singleton and my session spring BO get updated), go to another page, user adds related data, submits and goes to a confirmation page.  The confirm page has a button to go back, which clears all the selections.

Comment: The users weren't hitting this button... they would get to the confirm screen and logout.  Now the selections in the singleton are still there and the next user inherits them.  Now that I understand this better, I see that using a singleton to fetch is bad on many other levels past the issue I see here.  So, long story short, I will be changing that Spring Bean to seesion scope (along with the others).  I don't think performance will be an issue... if this app has more than 3 concurrent sessions at any given time, I would be surprised.

Comment: This is a very good question. I agree with you by using session scope, everything work fine. My thinking was whether this will cause the JVM run out of memory if there are 100,000 users. Another thing is data source connection issue. You mention DAO thing, I assume you have declare data source connection with Spring, and then you tied it to DAO, when there are 100,000 users in the session, and each session is holding one connection. I am not sure how Spring could handle this? I'm urge to look for more info on this area.